# How to use oleoresin capsicum (chilli extract)?

Tags: flavor, spices, spicy-hot

**How do you use the food additive *oleoresin capsicum*? How to enhance its spiciness?**

I made a few attempts with 1-2 drops per person in dishes already spiced with lots of chillies. However, the additive seems to cause more stomach pains than heat in the mouth...

I have tried:

- Mixing the few drops in a very thick base sauce and then add it to the rest of a more liquid (watery) sauce.
- Mixing a few drops in oil. They mix quite well, but not entirely. Then put the oil in the dish.

My guess is that the oleoresin does not dilute or dissolve well in the dish and stays confined in fat globules, so that they go straight through the stomach without interacting much with the mouth.

Comment: Buy some ghost pepper sauce or the full pepper or something instead and use that.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to add this after cooking, or add it anytime in the process?

Comment: @GdD It can be added anytime.

Comment: If it didn't work well with water or oil, I would try alcohol.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to, I suspect you can add it to oil to dissolve/dilute it before adding to your dish. I know you said you tried that, but it really should work if you mix the oil well (possibly with heating), and incorporate it well into the dish. If it still doesn't work, then perhaps the extract you have doesn't have the right balance of compounds.

But even if it works, at that point you might as well just use chili oil, or really any spicy sauce that you like. There are plenty that are hot enough to not need tons, and get your food plenty hot. It'll be less fussy to use, and less risk of accidentally throwing everything off with a drop too much.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Oleoresin paprika in some of spices,And it is well mixed, but before mixing you have to dilute it with Oil in recipe,Or mix